# Javascript/Razor Request.Params A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client

Tags: javascript, validation, razor

This javascript line gives me `A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client`

```
$('a[href=#tabs1-pane' + @Request.Params["index"] + ']').tab('show');
```

Normally i would solve these issues by setting [ValidateInput(false)]  on the controller, but how do i solve this in a view/javascript?

Comment: I don't think the issue is in this line. More like `index` contains something that it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you

```
var tempdate=@Request.Params["index"];
$('a[href=#tabs1-pane' + tempdate.tostring()  + ']').tab('show');
```